Why pick up the arba minim prior to making the bracha?
Brachos need to be made as close to the fulfillment of the mitzvah as possible
As one fulfills arba minim as soon as they are lifted then the natural place for the bracha should be immediately prior to picking them up
The prevailing minhag of holding them with intention not to fulfill the mitzvah or holding the esrog upside down etc seems unnecessary
(It is akin to say binding the retzuos with intention not to fulfill the mitzvah yet or initially binding the tefillin out of place)
Is it because we'd like to have the mitzvah object in hand when making the bracha?

Tosafot Sukkah 39a s.v. over la-assiyatan write:

מטעם זה צריך לברך אלולב קודם שיטלנו דאי לאחר שנטלו מדאגבהיה נפק ביה כדאמרי' בסוף פירקין (סוכה דף מב.) ומיהו לא מסתבר כלל דהיאך יברך עליו והוא מונח בכלי הא אמר בהקומץ רבה (מנחות לה: ושם) תפילין מאימתי מברך עליהן משעת הנחה עד שעת קשירה וכל שעה שאין המצוה מזומנת בידו לעשות לא מיסתבר כלל לברך עליו

To summarise their point: while it is true that at first glance one would expect that the correct procedure would be to make the blessing before picking up the lulav, it actually doesn’t make sense to make the blessing before the mitzvah item is in one’s hand and ready for the performance of the mitzvah.
Tosafot go on to offer three suggestions (two of which you list in your question) as to how one can make the blessing while the lulav is in his hand but before fulfilling the mitzvah.
Rambam Hilchot Lulav 7:6, on the other hand, does arguably write to do exactly as you suggest - first make the blessing and then pick up the lulav (although even this is not totally clear cut - compare with what he writes in Hilchot Berachot 11:15, where he allows and possibly prefers that the blessing be recited after picking up the lulav).
For the sake of completeness, I’ll note the opinion of Ran (Sukkah 20b midapei harif s.v. umiderparchinan) who writes that one simply makes the blessing after picking up the lulav even though he has already fulfilled the mitzvah, because he still has yet to wave it and complete the mitzvah totally.
Shulchan Aruch Orach Chaim 651:5 rules like the first two suggestions of Tosafot (blessing between picking up the lulav and the etrog, or blessing while holding the etrog upside-down) and Beiur HaGra (quoted in Mishnah Berurah :25) prefers the third suggestion of Tosafot (holding the lulav with intent not to fulfill the mitzvah until after the blessing is made). So, that’s why common practice is as you see, rather than making the blessing before picking up the lulav.

Rambam's position isn't as simple as you suggest. See Brachot 11:16 where he allows making the blessing after picking up. He may even indicate it's the standard expected practice (like the Ran and most Rishonim)

Another important note, the ShA is actually contradicting himself here (as the Gra points out). Tosafot holds that זה אחר זה doesn't work for Lulav, so his suggestions work. But for ShA (and "us") after picking up the Lulav you now only need to say a blessing on the Etrog על נטילת אתרוג. The only way to accept the ShA is to say you have kavana not be yotzei זה אחר זה but then why not go all the way. Indeed given the rishonim who davka prefer after and the machlokes of the nusach for before, the best suggestion is like the Gra על תנאי that if Ran is right you are yotzei before the bracha

Your diyuk in Rambam is from his language in Brachot? Seems to me that the straightforward reading in Lulav argues against that (although I accept that even there it’s not without question, as he mentions על נטילת לולב instead of the expected ליטול). What is Yemenite practice? Bracha before or after picking up?

Both those points are reasonable (always (even in 7:15) using the nusach על נטילת , and also listing the before-bracha as an afterthought) and perhaps also he says 11:8 ואימתיי מברך--בשעה שיישב בסוכה, או כשינענע הלולב which sounds like the default practice is before the naanuim not before the netila. None of it is 100% muchrach but I'm just suggesting that "that’s why common practice is as you see, rather than like Rambam rules" may also include that the Rambam doesn't necessarily even hold that, or at least doesn't think it's such a big deal to do otherwise.

@DoubleAA fair points. I’ve edited

Thank you. I don't understand the proof from tefillin. There one can progress up until the binding without initiating the mitzvah, as opposed to here.

@Nahum That’s true, but why is the Gemara insistent that you can’t say the beracha when the tefillin are still in their container? Must be, say the rishonim, that if you’re not holding the item it’s not considered עובר לעשייתן, and a beracha then is premature. That same logic also applies to lulav.

'עובר לעשייתן' mandates positioning the bracha as close to the mitzvah as possible with nothing non-essential intervening. Putting tefillin on without binding them, which legally isn't a kiyum mitzvah, can easily be seen to be a function of the 'עובר לעשייתן' requirement. I fail to see where Tosafos mines this new concept of having the mitzvah object in hand from.

See too the Ran's language in Pesachim https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=43555&st=&pgnum=206 נראה שתקנת חכמים היא שלא לברך עליו אלא לאחר נטילתו שאם יברך קודם לכך יהא סבור שמצוותו בנטילה לבד ולא ינענעו Meaning Rishonim who are saying "you can still say the bracha after because of naanuim" aren't just answering tosafot's question by saying bedieved that's still ok, but rather that's how chazal want you to do it.

Brachos are made at varying points in relation to the mitzvah being done. For example it's said after washing, it's said while putting on a tallis, it's said at the start of putting on tefilin, and it's said in regards to learning torah prior to learning anything. There are all unique reasons for why we say the bracha on each of the mitzvos. For lulav the fulfilling of the mitzvah is started by bringing the lulav and earog together and in the correct order. Seemingly if all species are not held together in the right order while shaking them you aren't fulfilling the mitzvah yet. Some want to already be holding all of the species when saying the bracha hence holding it upside down but will then change it at the last moment when bringing them together while others such as myself will only pick the esrog up after finishing the bracha. Either way the idea being to be able to bring the species together and wave them as close to saying the bracha as possible
